# Google Drive API for Android: Uploading Files to specific Drive "without" log in

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I've been googling for a solution to this for a while now, but that's hard to do if you don't even know what it's called that you're looking for.
Yes, the Google Drive API for Android obviously. But there are so many different usages, with so many different flows etc...

My app is supposed to upload files to a Google Drive. This Drive should be specified by the user. But instead of authorizing via logging in as a user, the App itself should be authorized. Something like this:

1. User pecifies Drive (as email/account/id/wtvr)
2. The owner of the Drive is notified ("Do you want to give xy/app permission to blabla")
3. The owner agrees
4. The app can now upload files to the drive by itself, no further log in needed from user

If possible, the Drive owner shouldn't have to authorize every single use of the app.

I did something like this very bodgily before (Google Drive Scripts, POST requests, etc., Ugly stuff), but would like to do it proper this time. Would be great if you could point me in the general direction of how to achieve this.

Comment: AFAIK, that is how it should work. When a user runs your app initially, that is when you get permission from them. Also, as long as they didn't revoke it, your app shouldn't ask for a permission from them. You can try their [quickstart](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/master/drive/quickstart) or [samples](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/examples/).

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Ah, but the Google Drive is not the users. Imagine you have a Drive, and you have an App. Every instance of the App (/every user) should automatically upload a file to the Google Drive. That's the gist of it, don't know why I explained it so weirdly.